# Passing array of nodes to function and returning an array of nodes

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

This is where I want to create a funciton where I can pass an array of 
structs called node

declearing the function

```
void shellSort(node* arr[]);

node* arrayz;
arrayz = new node[counterElements]
```

how I call the function

```
shellSort(arrayz);

//How I define the function
void lists::shellSort(node* arrayz[])
{
//code here
}
```

The error says void lists::shellSort(node**) does not match any in class lists //my class is called lists

Comment: Declaration of `shellSort(node*)` and defination of `shellSort(node* arrayz[])` are different. You should define as `shellSort(node* arrayz)`.

Comment: You should think of passing `number of items` in array. Otherwise you will not know length of arrary in `shellSort` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `number of items` in the array to the 'shellSort` function. Based on that the declaration of the function should be:

```
void lists::shellSort(node* arrayz, int nItems)
{
    //code here
}
//You should call this function as
node* arrayz;
arrayz = new node[counterElements]
shellSort(arrayz, counterElements);
```